# Highcharts with Google Analytics Oauth 2.0

Tags: php, oauth, highcharts, google-analytics

For some time i had a working Highchart with Google Analytics with the followigh code:

```
<?php

  // session_start for caching
  session_start();

  require 'analytics.class.php';

  try {

      // construct the class
      $oAnalytics = new analytics('XXXXXXXXX@mail.com', 'PASSXXXXX');

      // set it up to use caching
      $oAnalytics->useCache();

      $oAnalytics->setProfileById('ga:XXXXXXXXX');

      $current=date("Y-m-d",time());
      $previous=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("- 30 day", time()));
      $oAnalytics->setDateRange($previous, $current);

      //put visitors to array
      $visitorlst=$oAnalytics->getVisitors();
      //put new visitors to array
      $newvisitorlst=$oAnalytics->getNewVisitors();
      // use dimensions and metrics for output
      // see: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html  IMPORTANT

  } catch (Exception $e) { 
      echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
  }
  $allarray='';
  $newarray='';
  $thedate=$previous;
  $n=30;
  $j=30;
  foreach( $visitorlst as $val)
  {
    $n--;
      $da = explode("-", $thedate);
    $mon=$da[1]-1;
    $allarray.="[Date.UTC(".$da[0].",".$mon.",".$da[2]."), ".$val."],";
    $thedate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("- ".$n." day", time()));
  }
  $thedate=$previous;
  foreach( $newvisitorlst as $val)
  {
    $j--;    
      $da = explode("-", $thedate);
    $month=$da[1]-1;
    $newarray.="[Date.UTC(".$da[0].",".$month.",".$da[2]."), ".$val."],";
    $thedate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("- ".$j." day", time()));
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo hightchart with GA</title>
<meta name="description" content="This is an example to show how to get GA by PHP then parse it to JS" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script>

$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {

                renderTo: 'container',

                type: 'line',

                marginRight: 130,

                marginBottom: 25

            },

            title: {
            text: 'Daily visits at www.XXXXXXX.net'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
            tickWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: -3
            }
        },

        yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }, { // right y axis
            linkedTo: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }],

        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                pageOrigin: {
                                    x: this.pageX,
                                    y: this.pageY
                                },
                                headingText: this.series.name,
                                maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
                                    this.y +' visits',
                                width: 200
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },

            series: [
            /*{

                name: 'Chrome',
                data:[[Date.UTC(1999,  9, 27,4,0,0,0), 23.6   ],
                [Date.UTC(1999, 10, 10), 33.06],
                [Date.UTC(1999, 10, 18), 23.6 ],
            ]
                //data: [23.6, 24.15, 26.11, 27.46, 30.13, 33.06, 36.41, 37.23, 36.71, 37.01, 40.67, 41.52]

            },*/ 
            {

            name: 'All visits',
            data:[
                <?php echo $allarray; ?>
            ]},{
            name: 'New visitors',
            data:[
                <?php echo $newarray; ?>
            ]
                //data: [46.42, 47.24, 47.19, 46.97, 45.79, 44.09, 42.56, 40.85, 42.07, 41.06, 38.58, 38.27]

            }]

        });

    });

});

</script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And it comes with analytics.class.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Google Analytics PHP API
 * 
 * This class can be used to retrieve data from the Google Analytics API with PHP
 * It fetches data as array for use in applications or scripts
 *  
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 *
 * Credits: http://www.alexc.me/
 * parsing the profile XML to a PHP array
 *   
 *
 * @link http://www.swis.nl
 * @copyright 2009 SWIS BV
 * @author Vincent Kleijnendorst - SWIS BV (vkleijnendorst [AT] swis [DOT] nl)
 * 
 * @version 0.1
 */
  class analytics{

    private $_sUser;
    private $_sPass;
    private $_sAuth;
    private $_sProfileId;

    private $_sStartDate;
    private $_sEndDate;

    private $_bUseCache;
    private $_iCacheAge;

    /**
    * public constructor
    * 
    * @param string $sUser
    * @param string $sPass
    * @return analytics
    */
    public function __construct($sUser, $sPass){
        $this->_sUser = $sUser;
        $this->_sPass = $sPass;

        $this->_bUseCache = false;

        $this->auth();
    }


    /**
    * Google Authentification, returns session when set
    */
    private function auth(){

        if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
            $this->_sAuth = $_SESSION['auth'];
            return;
        }

        $aPost = array ( 'accountType'   => 'GOOGLE', 
                         'Email'         => $this->_sUser,
                         'Passwd'        => $this->_sPass,
                         'service'       => 'analytics',
                         'source'        => 'SWIS-Webbeheer-4.0');

        $sResponse = $this->getUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', $aPost);

        $_SESSION['auth'] = '';
        if (strpos($sResponse, "\n") !== false){
            $aResponse = explode("\n", $sResponse);
            foreach ($aResponse as $sResponse){
                if (substr($sResponse, 0, 4) == 'Auth'){
                    $_SESSION['auth'] = trim(substr($sResponse, 5));
                }
            }
        }
        if ($_SESSION['auth'] == ''){
            unset($_SESSION['auth']);
            throw new Exception('Retrieving Auth hash failed!');
        }
        $this->_sAuth = $_SESSION['auth']; 
    }

    /**
    * Use caching (bool)
    * Whether or not to store GA data in a session for a given period
    * 
    * @param bool $bCaching (true/false)
    * @param int $iCacheAge seconds (default: 10 minutes)
    */
    public function useCache($bCaching = true, $iCacheAge = 600){
        $this->_bUseCache = $bCaching;
        $this->_iCacheAge = $iCacheAge;
        if ($bCaching && !isset($_SESSION['cache'])){
            $_SESSION['cache'] = array();     
        }
    }


    /**
    * Get GA XML with auth key
    * 
    * @param string $sUrl
    * @return string XML
    */
    private function getXml($sUrl){

        return $this->getUrl($sUrl, array(), array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $this->_sAuth));
    }


    /**
    * Sets GA Profile ID  (Example: ga:12345)
    */        
    public function setProfileById($sProfileId){

            $this->_sProfileId = $sProfileId; 
    }

    /**
    * Sets Profile ID by a given accountname
    * 
    */
    public function setProfileByName($sAccountName){

        if (isset($_SESSION['profile'])){
            $this->_sProfileId = $_SESSION['profile'];
            return;
        }

        $this->_sProfileId = '';
        $sXml = $this->getXml('https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default');
        $aAccounts = $this->parseAccountList($sXml);

        foreach($aAccounts as $aAccount){
            if (isset($aAccount['accountName']) && $aAccount['accountName'] == $sAccountName){
                if (isset($aAccount['tableId'])){
                    $this->_sProfileId =  $aAccount['tableId'];
                }
            }    
        }
        if ($this->_sProfileId == ''){
            throw new Exception('No profile ID found!');
        }

        $_SESSION['profile'] = $this->_sProfileId;
    }

    /**
    * Returns an array with profileID => accountName
    * 
    */
    public function getProfileList(){

        $sXml = $this->getXml('https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default');
        $aAccounts = $this->parseAccountList($sXml);
        $aReturn = array();
        foreach($aAccounts as $aAccount){ 
            $aReturn[$aAccount['tableId']] =  $aAccount['title'];
        }       
        return $aReturn;
    }

    /**
    * get resulsts from cache if set and not older then cacheAge
    * 
    * @param string $sKey
    * @return mixed cached data
    */
    private function getCache($sKey){

        if ($this->_bUseCache === false){
            return false;
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId])){
            $_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId] = array();
        }  
        if (isset($_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId][$sKey])){
            if (time() - $_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId][$sKey]['time'] < $this->_iCacheAge){
                return $_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId][$sKey]['data'];
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
    * Cache data in session
    * 
    * @param string $sKey
    * @param mixed $mData Te cachen data
    */
    private function setCache($sKey, $mData){

        if ($this->_bUseCache === false){
            return false;
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId])){
            $_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId] = array();
        }  
        $_SESSION['cache'][$this->_sProfileId][$sKey] = array(  'time'  => time(),
                                                                'data'  => $mData);
    }

    /**
    * Parses GA XML to an array (dimension => metric)
    * Check http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html 
    * for usage of dimensions and metrics
    * 
    * @param array  $aProperties  (GA properties: metrics & dimensions)
    * 
    * @return array result
    */
    public function getData($aProperties = array()){
        $aParams = array();
        foreach($aProperties as $sKey => $sProperty){
            $aParams[] = $sKey . '=' . $sProperty;
        }

        $sUrl = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=' . $this->_sProfileId . 
                                                        '&start-date=' . $this->_sStartDate . 
                                                        '&end-date=' . $this->_sEndDate . '&' . 
                                                        implode('&', $aParams);
        $aCache = $this->getCache($sUrl);
        if ($aCache !== false){
            return $aCache;
        }

        $sXml = $this->getXml($sUrl);

        $aResult = array();

        $oDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $oDoc->loadXML($sXml);
        $oEntries = $oDoc->getElementsByTagName('entry');
        foreach($oEntries as $oEntry){
            $oTitle = $oEntry->getElementsByTagName('title');
            $sTitle = $oTitle->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $oMetric = $oEntry->getElementsByTagName('metric'); 

            // Fix the array key when multiple dimensions are given
            if (strpos($sTitle, ' | ') !== false && strpos($aProperties['dimensions'], ',') !== false){

                $aDimensions = explode(',', $aProperties['dimensions']);
                $aDimensions[] = '|';
                $aDimensions[] = '=';
                $sTitle = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim(str_replace($aDimensions, '', $sTitle)));  

            }
            $sTitle = str_replace($aProperties['dimensions'] . '=', '', $sTitle);

            $aResult[$sTitle] = $oMetric->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
        }
        // cache the results (if caching is true)
        $this->setCache($sUrl, $aResult);

        return $aResult;
    }

    /**
    * Parse XML from account list
    * 
    * @param string $sXml
    */
    private function parseAccountList($sXml){

        $oDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $oDoc->loadXML($sXml);
        $oEntries = $oDoc->getElementsByTagName('entry');
        $i = 0;
        $aProfiles = array();
        foreach($oEntries as $oEntry){

            $aProfiles[$i] = array();
            $oTitle = $oEntry->getElementsByTagName('title');
            $aProfiles[$i]["title"] = $oTitle->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $oEntryId = $oEntry->getElementsByTagName('id');
            $aProfiles[$i]["entryid"] = $oEntryId->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $oProperties = $oEntry->getElementsByTagName('property');
            foreach($oProperties as $oProperty){
                if (strcmp($oProperty->getAttribute('name'), 'ga:accountId') == 0){
                    $aProfiles[$i]["accountId"] = $oProperty->getAttribute('value');
                }    
                if (strcmp($oProperty->getAttribute('name'), 'ga:accountName') == 0){
                    $aProfiles[$i]["accountName"] = $oProperty->getAttribute('value');
                }
                if (strcmp($oProperty->getAttribute('name'), 'ga:profileId') == 0){
                    $aProfiles[$i]["profileId"] = $oProperty->getAttribute('value');
                }
                if (strcmp($oProperty->getAttribute('name'), 'ga:webPropertyId') == 0){
                    $aProfiles[$i]["webPropertyId"] = $oProperty->getAttribute('value');
                }
            }
            $oTableId = $oEntry->getElementsByTagName('tableId');
            $aProfiles[$i]["tableId"] = $oTableId->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $i++;
        }
        return $aProfiles;
    }

    /**
    * Get data from given URL
    * Uses Curl if installed, falls back to file_get_contents if not
    * 
    * @param string $sUrl
    * @param array $aPost
    * @param array $aHeader
    * @return string Response
    */
    private function getUrl($sUrl, $aPost = array(), $aHeader = array()){


        if (count($aPost) > 0){
            // build POST query
            $sMethod = 'POST'; 
            $sPost = http_build_query($aPost);    
            $aHeader[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            $aHeader[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($sPost);
            $sContent = $aPost;
        } else {
            $sMethod = 'GET';
            $sContent = null;
        }

        if (function_exists('curl_init')){
            // If Curl is installed, use it!
            $rRequest = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($rRequest, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
            curl_setopt($rRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            if ($sMethod == 'POST'){
                curl_setopt($rRequest, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
                curl_setopt($rRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aPost); 
            } else {
                curl_setopt($rRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aHeader);
            }

            $sOutput = curl_exec($rRequest);
            if ($sOutput === false){
                throw new Exception('Curl error (' . curl_error($rRequest) . ')');    
            }

            $aInfo = curl_getinfo($rRequest);

            if ($aInfo['http_code'] != 200){
                // not a valid response from GA
                if ($aInfo['http_code'] == 400){
                    throw new Exception('Bad request (' . $aInfo['http_code'] . ') url: ' . $sUrl);     
                }
                if ($aInfo['http_code'] == 403){
                    throw new Exception('Access denied (' . $aInfo['http_code'] . ') url: ' . $sUrl);     
                }
                throw new Exception('Not a valid response (' . $aInfo['http_code'] . ') url: ' . $sUrl);
            }

            curl_close($rRequest);

        } else {
            // Curl is not installed, use file_get_contents

            // create headers and post
            $aContext = array('http' => array ( 'method' => $sMethod,
                                                'header'=> implode("\r\n", $aHeader) . "\r\n",
                                                'content' => $sContent));
            $rContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
            $sOutput = @file_get_contents($sUrl, 0, $rContext);
            if (strpos($http_response_header[0], '200') === false){
                // not a valid response from GA   
                throw new Exception('Not a valid response (' . $http_response_header[0] . ') url: ' . $sUrl);       
            }
        }
        return $sOutput;
    }   

    /**
    * Sets the date range for GA data
    * 
    * @param string $sStartDate (YYY-MM-DD)
    * @param string $sEndDate   (YYY-MM-DD)
    */
    public function setDateRange($sStartDate, $sEndDate){

        $this->_sStartDate = $sStartDate; 
        $this->_sEndDate   = $sEndDate;

    }

    /**
    * Sets de data range to a given month
    * 
    * @param int $iMonth
    * @param int $iYear
    */
    public function setMonth($iMonth, $iYear){  

        $this->_sStartDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($iYear . '-' . $iMonth . '-01')); 
        $this->_sEndDate   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($iYear . '-' . $iMonth . '-' . date('t', strtotime($iYear . '-' . $iMonth . '-01'))));
    }

    /**
    * Get visitors for given period
    * 
    */
    public function getVisitors(){

        return $this->getData(array( 'dimensions' => 'ga:day',
                                     'metrics'    => 'ga:visits',
                                     'sort'       => 'ga:day'));
    }

    /**
    * Get pageviews for given period
    * 
    */    
    public function getPageviews(){

        return $this->getData(array( 'dimensions' => 'ga:day',
                                     'metrics'    => 'ga:pageviews',
                                     'sort'       => 'ga:day'));
    }

    /**
    * Get visitors per hour for given period
    * 
    */    
    public function getVisitsPerHour(){

        return $this->getData(array( 'dimensions' => 'ga:hour',
                                     'metrics'    => 'ga:visits',
                                     'sort'       => 'ga:hour'));
    }

    /**
    * Get Browsers for given period
    * 
    */    
    public function getBrowsers(){

        $aData = $this->getData(array(  'dimensions' => 'ga:browser,ga:browserVersion',
                                        'metrics'    => 'ga:visits',
                                        'sort'       => 'ga:visits'));             
        arsort($aData);
        return $aData;                                                                                                                                                                           
    }

    /**
    * Get Operating System for given period
    * 
    */    
    public function getOperatingSystem(){

        $aData = $this->getData(array(   'dimensions' => 'ga:operatingSystem',
                                         'metrics'    => 'ga:visits',
                                         'sort'       => 'ga:visits'));
        // sort descending by number of visits
        arsort($aData);
        return $aData; 
    }
    /**
    * Get screen resolution for given period
    * 
    */    
    public function getScreenResolution(){

        $aData = $this->getData(array(   'dimensions' => 'ga:screenResolution',
                                         'metrics'    => 'ga:visits',
                                         'sort'       => 'ga:visits'));

        // sort descending by number of visits 
        arsort($aData);
        return $aData; 
    }

    /**
    * Get referrers for given period
    * 
    */    
    public function getReferrers(){

        $aData = $this->getData(array(   'dimensions' => 'ga:source',
                                         'metrics'    => 'ga:visits',
                                         'sort'       => 'ga:source'));

        // sort descending by number of visits 
        arsort($aData);
        return $aData; 
    }

    /**
    * Get search words for given period
    * 
    */    
    public function getSearchWords(){
        $aData = $this->getData(array(   'dimensions' => 'ga:keyword',
                                         'metrics'    => 'ga:visits',
                                         'sort'       => 'ga:keyword'));
        // sort descending by number of visits                                                                                                                                                     
        arsort($aData);
        return $aData; 
    }
}
```

But Google change the Oauth so i need to implement the new authorize system like https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP
prefered with service account.
Anyone has change the old implementation with new Oauth2?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php). It is an updated quickstart guide and should give you the steps necessary to query the API with a service account.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes the idea of how to work is there in your link, but is lots of road to cover if you dont have the full knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search i have come with a person with similar code of me but who update it and adopt it recently in new Oath 2.0.
I take the code from here and finnaly i get a working copy again. I case of someone come with same problem.
http://www.mustafaercel.com/2015/07/google-analytics-verilerini-php-ile-web-sayfamiza-cekelim-2015/